# Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled. - How to solve this problem?

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I'm wanting to use web automation in python, with selenium, I'm currently using Microsoft Edge as a browser, but whenever I run my code, this error appears and opens a new Microsoft Edge window for a few seconds, then closes right away.

Python version I use: Python 3.11
Microsoft Edge and MS Edge WebDriver Version: 114.0.1823.67
Selenium Version: 4.10.0

I've tried using Google Chrome too, but the same error happens.

Code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Edge()
```

Error:

```
ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)
ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
```

What was expected was that a new window opened in my Microsoft Edge browser. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mistake you are making is by using selenium 4.10.0, because selenium is only compatible with Microsoft Edge browser up to version 3, above that it is incompatible.
Try installing an older version of selenium, run the following code in the terminal:

pip install selenium version 3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium to automate Microsoft Edge, you must use Selenium 4; Selenium 3 is no longer supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp

Be sure your webdriver version and browser version are the same
The experimental option detach is what will keep the browser open

So try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

service = Service("./msedgedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.apple.com/")
```